# mock UrlMapping in TagLib unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I'm using Grails 2.3.11, and have a customized `taglib` (`AuditTagLib`), which in turn calls the `createLink()` function.

Now I'm writing unit test for `AuditTagLib`, but (obviouse) the resultant url from `createLink()` depends on the entries in `UrlMapping`.

I think the unit test does not pick up from `UrlMapping` from `conf`, instead it uses some empty/defaults, which gave a different resultant url from `createLink()` from my run-app.

How to inject/setup a mock `UrlMapping` such that `createLink()` renders the same url as in my running grails app?

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by adding into the unit test:
`grailsApplication.addArtefact(UrlMappingsArtefactHandler.TYPE, new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().classLoader).parseClass(new File("grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy")))`

Ref: 
https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9037